# Regex in ruby to enclose word before : with double quotes

Tags: ruby, regex, json, gsub

I have a string which I want to convert in json string

Following is the format of the json

```
               title: {
                    position: "bottom",
                    text: "Share of Internet Population Growth"
                },
                legend: {
                    visible: false
                },
                chartArea: {
                    background: ""
                },
                seriesDefaults: {
                    type: "donut",
                    startAngle: 150
                }
```

To convert it toa JSON string i need to replace the `AnyKey:` with `"AnyKey":`
I was reading about gsub. What can be exact regex to replace this kind of string

Thanks in advance

Comment: You just do `require 'json'` and then `your_hash.to_json`.. You are done!! Read [this doco](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#module-JSON-label-Generating+JSON).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(\w+)(?=:)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/zR2tR4/3

Replace by `"$1"`.

Comment: That did not replaces all the keys

Comment: Many keys missed such as title:,legend:,chartArea: